# Matplotlib-change value size

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the size of the `x` and `y` values, in `matplotlib`.

This is the current plot code:

```
time = [p[0]for p in data]
ch1 = [p[1] for p in data]
ch2 = [p[2]for p in data]


plt.plot(time,ch1,time,ch2)
plt.xlabel(header[0],fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)',fontsize = 20)
plt.legend(header[1:])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question in order to make clear what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried?

Comment: Also please provide a [minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think by size you mean the line thickness or the masker size. Just search for changing line thickness and marker size in matplotlib

Comment: @Bazingaa  I want to change the visable-size of the x-values and y values. For example seconds(0-100), and voltage(-5,5), so they will be more visable.  (want the numbers to be bigger)

Comment: I think you mean the limits of the x and y axis. You can use `plt.xlim(0, 100)` and `plt.ylim(-5,5)`